# I took an image from entire hard disk of a real PC running linux FC4 and try to run it under virtual box but grub freezes all the time

Tags: fedora, grub, rescue

I am trying to run an image which I took from an actual PC (cpu = intel/motherboard=unknown to me/ os = FC 4/ RAID disk controller) and I want to run that image under virtual machine (vmware/virtualbox/virtual SCSI disk controller/cpu=amd) and all the time grub will freeze on following line :
"GRUB "

I have used FC4 rescue cd and tried following commands :

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage/
grub-install /dev/sda/

error : does not have any corresponding BIOS drive.
```

or

```
grub
find /boot/.....
error : Error 15: File not found
```

Honestly, I don't have any idea how I can fix this image so it would run under virtual machine.

and this is my

```
fdisk -l
```

output
[image: redhat fedora core 4 screenshot]

Help please.

Comment: `/dev/sda/` would point to a directory, but `/dev/sda` is a file. Try it and see if it helps.

Comment: the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem,

Solution for my case :

after booting with rescue CD :

> chroot /mnt/sysimage/
>
> grub
>
> root (hd0,0)
>
> find /grub/grub.conf
>
> setup (hd0)
>
> reboot